# Why is this error happening when trying to export to GLTF/GLB?

Tags: python, export, gltf

I'm getting the following error when I try to export a simple 3D model as GLTF/GLB. I'm using the version `3.6.2` of Blender:

````
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 852, in execute
    return gltf2_blender_export.save(context, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 34, in save
    json, buffer = __export(export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 51, in __export
    __gather_gltf(exporter, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_export.py", line 65, in __gather_gltf
    active_scene_idx, scenes, animations = gltf2_blender_gather.gather_gltf2(export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather.py", line 28, in gather_gltf2
    scenes.append(__gather_scene(blender_scene, export_settings))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 35, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather.py", line 69, in __gather_scene
    node = gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.gather_node(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 34, in gather_node
    mesh=__gather_mesh(vnode, blender_object, export_settings),
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 242, in __gather_mesh
    result = gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.gather_mesh(blender_mesh,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 35, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.py", line 57, in gather_mesh
    primitives=__gather_primitives(blender_mesh, uuid_for_skined_data, vertex_groups, modifiers, materials, export_settings),
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.py", line 134, in __gather_primitives
    return gltf2_blender_gather_primitives.gather_primitives(blender_mesh,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 35, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_primitives.py", line 77, in gather_primitives
    material = gltf2_blender_gather_materials.gather_material(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 35, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\gltf2_blender_gather_materials.py", line 58, in gather_material
    extensions, uvmap_actives_extensions = __gather_extensions(blender_material, emissive_factor, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\gltf2_blender_gather_materials.py", line 256, in __gather_extensions
    specular_extension, use_actives_uvmap_specular = export_specular(blender_material, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\extensions\gltf2_blender_gather_materials_specular.py", line 151, in export_specular
    specularColorTexture, use_active_uvmap, specularColorFactor = gltf2_blender_gather_texture_info.gather_texture_info(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\gltf2_blender_gather_texture_info.py", line 22, in gather_texture_info
    return __gather_texture_info_helper(primary_socket, blender_shader_sockets, 'DEFAULT', filter_type, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 35, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\gltf2_blender_gather_texture_info.py", line 43, in __gather_texture_info_helper
    index, factor = __gather_index(blender_shader_sockets, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\gltf2_blender_gather_texture_info.py", line 140, in __gather_index
    return gltf2_blender_gather_texture.gather_texture(blender_shader_sockets, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 35, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\gltf2_blender_gather_texture.py", line 29, in gather_texture
    source, factor = __gather_source(blender_shader_sockets, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\gltf2_blender_gather_texture.py", line 81, in __gather_source
    return gltf2_blender_gather_image.gather_image(blender_shader_sockets, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 35, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\gltf2_blender_gather_image.py", line 44, in gather_image
    buffer_view, factor_buffer_view = __gather_buffer_view(image_data, mime_type, name, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 35, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\gltf2_blender_gather_image.py", line 98, in __gather_buffer_view
    data, factor = image_data.encode(mime_type, export_settings)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\extensions\gltf2_blender_image.py", line 142, in encode
    pixels, width, height, factor = self.numpy_calc(self.stored)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\extensions\gltf2_blender_texture_specular.py", line 84, in specular_calculation
    factors = [np.amax(out_buf[:, :, i]) for i in range(3)]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\exp\material\extensions\gltf2_blender_texture_specular.py", line 84, in <listcomp>
    factors = [np.amax(out_buf[:, :, i]) for i in range(3)]
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in amax
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2793, in amax
    return _wrapreduction(a, np.maximum, 'max', axis, None, out,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.6\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 86, in _wrapreduction
    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity```
````

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: I needed to delete a material that, for some reason, was causing it to glitch.