# Having an Issue while exporting character with rig into gltf

Tags: python, rigging, export, gltf

I've recently delved into learning animation in Blender over the past few months. With some guidance from a friend who works in the industry, I've been able to work with a base character that's already rigged. I've become relatively comfortable working with the rig, but I've encountered an issue when attempting to export it as a glTF file. I have tried to export othe model that I made, and it works fine (mostly solid object without any armature or rig)

When I try export the rigged model, I'm confronted with a error message that starts with "**Python traceback (most recent call last)**" and contains the error statement "**ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity.**"

[image: Error Log 1]
[image: Error Log 2]

here is the blend file that I mentioned (I use dropbox because blend exchange only to limited to 30mb) https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2j2nf7op7e2y3xo46khad/Mpuu.blend?rlkey=9xymzi9yqrg3sgqxhwp0b801h&dl=0

I am fairly new to the scene and I have trouble to know what caused the error. should I re-rig the Character, or is there any solution I should try?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I do have some advices for performance and avoiding other potential issues down the road:

1. Apply your modeling modifiers like Mirror and Solidify on your meshes. When you animate a model, you want as few things to evaluate as possible, it's slow and can lead to issues. While doing that, also probably should put your armature modifier before subdivision modifier.
2. Subdivision modifiers can't use your GPU when you use autosmooth, plus autosmooth is also very slow to evaluate on deforming meshes. So, I highly advise you to disable it on all your character's meshes (<kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > Shade Smooth).
3. Select all your character's meshes and hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply Scale. Uneven scale can lead to unwanted transformations and might not be supported or correctly interpreted in other softwares.

After all that, following [this other answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/299583/53447), I removed all materials from your objects, and I was able to export. So there's probably at least one of your materials with some issue.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the suggestion, I realize some of the texture is missing and may contribute to the export failure. thank you for the answer